# What is the equivalent to $stateProvider from angularJS in angular 12?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I'm migrating code from AngularJS to Angular 12, what's equivalent to `$stateProvider` in angular 12?

I see that `$stateProvider` related to ui-router, can I use something from `AppRoutingModule` that gives the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To manage state in an modern version of Angular you have some different options. You can work with services and observables in order store your state and subscribe to it everytime you need it. You could also use per example libraries like https://ngrx.io/.